# Execute a cmdlet within a ForEach query

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I am attempting to run the following PowerShell command against my Exchange 2010 SP1 server:

```
$colItems = Get-Mailbox -Filter {office -eq "ExportPST"}
ForEach($objItem in $colItems)
{
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $objItem -FilePath \\server\share$\"$objItem".pst
}
```

When I do this I receive the error:

> Couldn't locate a database suitable for storing this request.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (domain.com....d/John Doe:MailboxOrMailUserIdParameter) [New-M    ailboxExportRequest],
>   MailboxDatabase...manentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 9322CB6D,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewMailboxExportRequest

What I am attempting to do is search across my AD users, locate users that have the string ExportPST in the Office field, and then export the command New-MailboxExportRequest to export the entire contents of the user's mailbox to a PST for each user returned.

When I add a Write-Host to the above, the outputed values are correct:

> New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox  jdoe  -FilePath " \\server\share$\John Doe.pst"

The output also includes an extra space between the -FilePath " and \, which I imagine will cause an issue once the above issue has been resolved, is there a way to contactenate strings without it adding this extra space?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: It will work the way you expect it as long as the value returned by casting "$objItem" **doesn't contain spaces**. I would go with Trevor's suggestion and make sure to double quote the whole path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your quoting is a bit off. Double-quoted string expansion works when you completely surround the string, not just the variable part.

```
$colItems = Get-Mailbox -Filter {office -eq "ExportPST"}
ForEach($objItem in $colItems)
{
  New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $objItem -FilePath "\\server\share$\$objItem.pst"
}
```

Here's an alternative syntax which uses .NET string formatting / replacement:

```
$colItems = Get-Mailbox -Filter {office -eq "ExportPST"}
ForEach($objItem in $colItems)
{
  New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $objItem -FilePath ('\\server\share$\{0}.pst' -f $objItem)
}
```

To make troubleshooting / debugging easier, you could assign the file path to a variable, and then pass the variable into the `-FilePath` parameter. That way you can see exactly which value is getting passed in.

```
$colItems = Get-Mailbox -Filter {office -eq "ExportPST"}
ForEach($objItem in $colItems)
{
  $FilePath = '\\server\share$\{0}.pst' -f $objItem;
  Write-Host -Object ('$FilePath value is: {0}' -f $FilePath);
  New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $objItem -FilePath $FilePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$objItem` is a string you can do:

```
-FilePath "\\server\share$\${objItem}.pst"
```

You can tell if it's a string by doing this:

```
$objItem.GetType().FullName
```

Even if it's not a string it still might work if the objects `ToString()` method provides the value you need because PowerShell will automatically call the `ToString()` method of the object and put it place in your string. So if this gives you the value you want: `$objItem.ToString()` then you may also use it. If there is a property however like $objItem.Name that you have to access then you will need to use string concatenation , a subexpression or .NET string formatting.

- Concatenation:           `-FilePath ("\\server\share$\" + $objItem.Name + ".pst")`
- Subexpression:           `-FilePath "\\server\share$\$($objItem.Name).pst"`
- .NET string formatting:  `-FilePath ("\\server\share$\{0}.pst" -f $objItem.Name)`